# jTable Master record Id not being sent on Child record's update request

Tags: javascript, jquery-jtable

```
  $('#PermissionGroupGrid').jtable({
        ajaxSettings: {
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        useBootstrap: true,
        pageSize: 5,
        title: 'List of Permission Group',
        actions: {
            listAction: '/PermissionGroup/List',
            deleteAction: '/PermissionGroup/Delete',
            updateAction: '/PermissionGroup/Update',
            createAction: '/PermissionGroup/Create'
        },
        defaultSorting: 'PermissionGroupName ASC',
        fields: {
            Id: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: false
            },
            Permissions: {
                title: 'Permissions',
                width: '5%',
                sorting: false,
                edit: false,
                create: false,
                display: function (permissionData) {
                    var $img = $('<img src="../../Images/list_metro.png" title="Assign Permissions" />');
                    $img.click(function () {
                        console.log(permissionData);
                        console.table(permissionData);
                        $('#PermissionGroupGrid').jtable('openChildTable',
                                $img.closest('tr'),
                                {
                                    ajaxSettings: {
                                        type: 'GET',
                                        dataType: 'json'
                                    },
                                    title: permissionData.record.PermissionGroupName + ' - Permissions',
                                    actions: {
                                        listAction: '/Permission/ListPermission?PermissionGroupId=1',
                                        deleteAction: '/Demo/DeleteExam',
                                        updateAction: '/Demo/UpdateExam',
                                        createAction: '/Demo/CreateExam'
                                    },
                                    fields: {
                                        PermissionGroupId: {
                                            type: 'hidden',
                                            defaultValue: permissionData.record.Id
                                        },
                                        Id: {
                                            key: true,
                                            create: false,
                                            edit: false,
                                            list: false
                                        },
                                        PermissionName: {
                                            title: 'Permission Name'
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, function (data) {
                                    data.childTable.jtable('load');
                                });
                    });

                    return $img;
                }
            },
            PermissionGroupName: {
                title: 'PermissionGroupTitle'
            }
        }
    });

    $('#PermissionGroupGrid').jtable('load');
```

When any of the child record is requesting for Update, child record's Id is being sent in the `GET` request but not the Id of the Master record. I followed the demo on `jtable.org` exactly. When `console.log` `'permissionData.record.Id'` I can see the master record's Id. FTR, both Master and Child table's key column has name 'Id'.

Can some one please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Based on jTable 2.4.0 debugging, defaultValue is used only on create form. If you are editting existing item record[fieldName] is used instead. In your case record["PermissionGroupId"]. That means you need to include PermissionGroupId field on your child record object to make it work.